# Do not reload all Flask apps

Tags: flask

I'm using flask blueprints just as written here:
http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/patterns/appdispatch/

Specifically, I'm running the following piece of code:

```
from werkzeug.wsgi import DispatcherMiddleware
from frontend_app import application as frontend
from backend_app import application as backend

application = DispatcherMiddleware(frontend, {
    '/backend':     backend
})
```

Flask has an awesome feature of reloading application as it detects change in code. However, in my case it is not desirable for both apps: backend app is too heavy to be reloaded every few minutes. When I reload fronend, backend gets reloaded as well and it takes too long. Is there any way to reload only app that was changed?

I realize it might be difficult, because as far as I understand at this point

```
application = DispatcherMiddleware(frontend, {
    '/backend':     backend
})
```

applications are merged into a single one and they are not separate anymore.

Anyway, maybe there is a different way to achieve what I want?

Thanks.

Comment: You are using the Debug=True of flask or something else for auto reload?

Comment: yes, I do use auto_reload=True

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if there is anything direct for doing such thing. Only thing I can think if you preventing a reinitialization of your module.

See a below example of how one can achieve this

**reloadme.py**

```
import sys

if 'reloadme' in sys.modules and hasattr(sys.modules['reloadme'], '__MODULE_LOADED'):
    print ("module is being reloaded")
    mod = sys.modules['reloadme']
    x = mod.x
else:
    print ("Loading module for first time")
    __MODULE_LOADED = True
    x = 2

def printx():
    print (x)
```

**reloadtest.py**

```
from importlib import reload

import reloadme

reloadme.printx()

reloadme.x = 10

reloadme.printx()

print("Reloading reloadme to check if x is changed back to 2")
reload(reloadme)

reloadme.printx()
```

The output of running `reloadtest.py` will be as below

```
Loading module for first time
2
10
Reloading reloadme to check if x is changed back to 2
Reloading module
10
```